# What's the set $\mathbb{N}_0$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In some papers I've seen the following set:

$$\mathbb{N}_0$$

What's the set $\mathbb{N}_0$?

---

This is from [here](https://www.kent.ac.uk/smsas/personal/lb209/files/sp07.pdf) (about Markov chain), page 4.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Notation

Comment: The german wikipedia gives even sources for the different definitions: $\mathbb{N}$ was introduced by Dedekind denoting the positive integers (Dedekind: Was sind und was sollen die Zahlen? Braunschweig 1888) and $\mathbb{N}_0$ by Peano denoting the nonnegative integers (Peano: Opere scelte. II, S. 124. Definition in: Peano: Opere scelte. III, S. 225) see: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat%C3%BCrliche_Zahl#Bezeichnungskonventionen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to know for sure without context, but it could mean the set of natural numbers including 0: $$\mathbb{N}_0 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \dots\}$$
There isn't universal agreement over whether $\mathbb{N}$ should refer to the natural numbers with or without 0, so some authors may write $\mathbb{N}_0$ to avoid any ambiguity.  You sometimes also see $\mathbb{N}_{\ge 0}$.